# Unable to handle error Powershell try with catch?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

> Hi, I write some PowerShell cmd to get the attribute of TransportRule.
>   I know that this('TA') particular  Transport rule does not **exist** in
>   the **exchange**, I handle that thing through **try with a catch** but I do
>   not get a correct result.

```
$temp="error"
Try{
Get-TransportRule -Identity TA|fl
}
Catch{
$temp
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please _edit the question_. Add your code and error messages as text, not as images. Pictures are hard to read, one cannot search those and copying any code requires extra effort. What's more, explain what's the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Try / Catch statement works only with terminating errors. 
You may try:

```
$temp="error"
Try{ 
    Get-TransportRule -Identity TA -ErrorAction Stop | Format-List 
} 
Catch{ 
    $temp
}
```

Another option would be to change it generally for the current session, setting the default variable `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. Then you do not need to use the `-ErrorAction` parameter.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the PowerShell window you should give it in a singe line like,

```
$temp="error"; Try{ Get-TransportRule -Identity TA|fl } Catch{ $temp }
```

The other way of doing this is, save it in a file with .ps1 extension and if you try to run that from powershell it will handle the exception.

[image]

If you use multiple lines, the command will be executed in the order and each line will be considered as a `separate command`. So in your image, it is executing line by line and when it comes to `Get-TransportRule` command it doesn't have any connection between try and catch because it's a separate command.

Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: Please edit the answer and explain _why_ single line would work instead of using multiple lines.